# Jersey JSON-Processing: add key-value pair to JsonObject

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0, json

I am using Jersey implementation to make Restful webservice in Java. To handle Json, I am using "Java API for JSON Processing (JSON-P)".

Inside `JsonObject`, there are already few entries and I want to add a new entry(Key-value pair).

I am not able to find a direct way to add a new entry(Key-value pair).

I can create a new `JsonObject`, traverse the old `JsonObject` and copy all the value in it to the new `JsonObject` and add a new entry in the new `JsonObject`. But is there any direct way to add a new entry into `JsonObject`?

Here is the code,

```
     JsonObject myJsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("key1", "value1")
    .add("key2", "value2")
    .build();
```

How can I add one more entry in the same `myJsonObject`?

Comment: Try looking in the docs. Frankly I didnt find the solution. Maybe you can. Here is the link. https://json-processing-spec.java.net/nonav/releases/1.0/fcs/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that there is no simpler way... A `JsonObject` is immutable, so you can't modify it directly. So you will need to create a new `JsonObjectBuilder` to create a different one. If you have an object looking like this:

```
 JsonObject myJsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
.add("key1", "value1")
.add("key2", "value2")
.build();
```

You can do the following:

```
JsonObjectBuilder builder = new JsonObjectBuilder();

for(Entry<String, JsonValue> entry : myJsonObject.entrySet()) {
  builder.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}

// modify key
builder.add("key1", "differentValue");
// add key
builder.add("key3", "newValue");

JsonObject newObject = builder.build();
```

But I guess it would be nice to have a convenience constructor `new JsonObjectBulder(existingJsonObject)` to get rid of the loop...

Edit: As an alternative you could look into [mapping technologies](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/).